# allow a Textarea to be null / empty when updating to a database using MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, textarea

I have a page on my MVC application where a user can edit / upload data to a database.

Basically the have a link on the site called "Admin", they click here, logon and are presented with a page that allows them to change / update data displayed on the "Special Offers" section of the site.

The "Admin" section contains a few textareas which display data contained in a database table. The user can then change the data displayed in these text areas and click an "Update" button which will then upload this data to the database, then the "Special Offers" page in the site displays this newly updated data to the public.

The issue I have is that if the user who is editing the data tries to update the database with textareas that that are empty of data then the "Special Offers" page will not load (it returns an error shown below). I have checked that the database table has the "Nullable" option set to "True", but this makes no difference.

### [Error]

Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source Error:

```
Line 25: @Html.Raw(tbl_special_offers.offer3.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))
```

---

This is the code that the "Special Offers" View uses to access the database and display the data (using Visual Web Developer Express):

```
@model IEnumerable<bhgc.Models.tbl_special_offers>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Special Offers";
}
<div>
    <fieldset>
            <legend>Special Offers</legend>
        <br />
        @foreach (var tbl_special_offers in Model)
        {

            <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%;">
                <div style="float: left; width: 40%; height: 50%; margin-left: 50px; border: 1px solid #ddd;  padding: 15px;">
                    @Html.Raw(tbl_special_offers.offer1.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "    <br/>"))
                </div>
                <div style="float: right; width: 40%; height: 50%; margin-right: 50px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 15px;">
                    @Html.Raw(tbl_special_offers.offer2.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "    <br/>"))
                </div>
            </div>


    }
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to either allow the field to be empty, or automatically append a space into the field when it is updated so that when the public view the "Special Offers" page it doesn't return an error?

The website and page in question is currently public at http://www.boarsheadgolfcentre.co.uk/Home/Special

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the item you are performing a Replace on null, why don't you try something like this

```
(tbl_special_offers.offer2 ?? String.Empty).Replace(...)
```

That way you shouldn't be replacing on `null`, and will (hopefully) avoid the exception.

Comment: Thank you Balthy, sorry one thing I should have added, is that I am using the `Replace(Environment.NewLine, "    <br/>")` part so as to preserve line breaks / formatting input from the textarea.

Comment: I updated the View code to look like this: `@Html.Raw(tbl_special_offers.offer1 ?? String.Empty.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))` which worked fine with the empty textarea, but unfortunately it removed the preservation of line breaks - any way to get round this?

Comment: Are you missing a set of ( ) parentheses?
@Html.Raw((tbl_special_offers.offer1 ?? String.Empty).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))

This way you are saying execute Replace(...) on tbl_special_offers.offer2 if it is not null, else execute it on String.Empty

Comment: Thanks again Balthy, I'm afraid I don't really know. I am an absolute beginner with all this (most help with code has been gained from either here or the original Razor MVC3 C# tutorial on the ASP.net website). I'm not familiar with various syntax's etc.

Comment: No problem, did that fix it? The `??` operator says _"Use the Left Operand if it not null, else use the Right Operand"_ You cannot execute a method on `null` so when you do something like this `(value1 ?? value2).Method()` it will execute Method() on `value1` if it can, otherwise it will use `value2`.

Comment: Thanks so much Balthy, it worked perfectly and your explanation was really helpful.